# how to access the object in c++ passed by javascript as a argument?

Tags: c++, opera

how to access the object in c++ passed by javascript as a argument?
in javascript world I have exported few c++ function. Now during function call from javascript
it passes a string and a object. The string I am able to find in c++ world but the object parameters I am not able to access.

```
<!--JAVASCRIPT WORLD START-->
var attr = {Name : "ABC", Address : "chennai", Mode : 0, Text : "tESt" };
SetMethod("KK", attr);
<!--JAVASCRIPT WORLD END>

//C++ WORLD START
SetMethod(jspp::function_context& context)
{
    const std::string NameinCPP = context.string(0);
    jspp::object obj = context.object(1);
    printf("Welcome %s",NameinCPP.c_str()); //This line is printing Welcome KK 
    /*I am not able to access obj attributes. 
    may someone suggest way to access the object details?*/ 
}
//C++ WORLD END
```

(jspp::object internally uses some ECMA engine)

Comment: What environment are you working in? Are you exclusively in a browser?  Are you writing a native browser addon?  Are you writing a desktop application? Where (in what context) will your javascript code execute? Where will your c++ code execute?

Comment: javascript code will execute in opera browser and a plugin kind of thing I am trying to implement

Comment: I am not trying to implement Desktop application. The C++ environment have access to call internal layer function which control hardware. In Embedded environment I am working in

Comment: Ok.  You're in an embedded environment.  This means that you are working in an unusual environment with special functionality and special restrictions.  It's probably n9t just a web browser... you need to specify details of the embedded environment if anyone is going to be able to advise you on how to program for it.

Comment: Through web browser I am trying to control hardware few basic functionality such as switching off/on setting some 12 hr clock or 24 hr clock on LED display.

Comment: Um... ok... but what web browser? What device are you going to be running on? What operating system?

Comment: Opera web browser, settop box, linux operating system

Comment: Good. Getting closer :-) .  Is the web browser running on the set top box?

Comment: yes like wise is the requirement from customer they may run some sort of application

Comment: Ok.  I am nit an expert in this space, but you have now defined the problem a bit better.  It seems that there are two major things that need to be considered. First, there is the challenge of writing an Opera add-on.  Then there is the challenge of any custom stuff that the set top environment imposes.  Specifying the set-top you're building for would help get questions.  You may well be stuck working with Opera, the settop vendor and their docunentation...